# How to fix this ' Using type org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.NoNodeException from an indirect dependency '?

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, bazel

The function is very simple:

```
  import org.apache.curator.framework.CuratorFramework;

  ...

  private final CuratorFramework curator;

  ...

  void deleteZkState() throws Exception {
    try {
      curator.delete().deletingChildrenIfNeeded().forPath("/myproject/mystate");
    } catch (NoNodeException e) {
      logger.info(e.getMessage());
    }
  }
```

However when I compile it I got this error at the `catch` statement:

> error: [strict] Using type org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.NoNodeException from an indirect
>   dependency

The zookeeper version is 3.4.14.

What is causing this error and how can I fix it?

java version is `openjdk 10.0.2 2018-07-17`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is actually caused by an error in the build configuration.

In the bazel's BUILD I should add the `zookeeper` dependency,.